# Reading local GeoJSON file using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geojson

I am using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.14.

I change the "url"  which only receive the "http"-start str  to "data",but it didn't work.

```
    const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
      data: "js/all_month.geojson",
      copyright: "USGS Earthquakes",
      popupTemplate: template,
      renderer: renderer //optional
    });
```

Comment: When you ran the code that you've presented how exactly did it not work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused, check again the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript Sandbox example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=layers-geojson).

The [url](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GeoJSONLayer.html#url) property is where you should put the source of the data, in your code `js/all_month.geojson`.

One more thing, *GeoJSONLayer* has no `data` property.